# Access a SaveMethod in DLL from MVC View

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, dll

I have a dll that contains a save method.  Right now I know can access this from my controller. Is it possible to access this method directly from the view using javascript and essentially perform the save action without calling the controller? 
I am not sure this is possible since you need to be able to create an instance of your model, populate it and then pass it to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript/Jquery can't directly interact with your dll (I consider your dll is a simple class library project). JavaScript/Jquery will call a methood/action in your Controller (you are already doing), action of WebAPI, WebService, WCF, Generic Handler (.ashx) etc. and this action will internally call save method of your dll.

Comment: What if it wasn't a DLL, but just a simple class?  Can I access the class from the view?  I know I can reference external .js files from the view, but what about a .NET class?

Comment: No, you can't directly, need to have some intermediate technology as mentioned above which can interact with your class.